# How to interpret probabilities from different time-intervals

Tags: probability, time-series

I have trained different models for prediction bankruptcy 1 year prior bankruptcy, 2 years and 3 years prior and so on. When I use the models on a single sample and I for example get following results:

1. $0.4$
2. $0.8$
3. $0.5$

So can I say that this company goes bankrupt most probably in 2nd year or should i say during 2 years time and with probability 80%?

Or should I calculate valid distribution so $(0.4 + 0.8 + 0.5 = 1.7)$ and

1. $0.24$
2. $0.47$
3. $0.29$

and now I can say that the bankruptcy happens in 2nd year with probability of 47%?

Thank you very much!

Comment: When your model gives you that the company will go bankrupt in 3 years with probability $0.5$, I assume that means the probability the company will go bankrupt in *exactly* the third year from now?  I.e., it doesn't mean "in the next three years"?

Comment: Well I trained the models with samples of bankrupted companies with corresponding data ie. when training 1 year prior bankrupty I used variables the bankrupted companies had 1 year prior bankruptcy, then training 2 years prior then the variables bankrupted companies had 2 years perior bankruptcy happened etc. So Im not sure if I can say that the model predicts if it happens during 3 years time or at 3rd year. I assume that I gives the probability of bankruptcy at 3rd year.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the numbers you have indicated ($.4$, $.8$, $.5$), it seems your model is pretty flawed (else, please state precisely what it is your model is calculating).  For, it calculates the probability of bankruptcy within the next three years to be $1.7$, which is larger than $100 \%$.  Maybe you just made these numbers up, and your model did not actually return them.

As long as you use mathematically precise wording, you can present whatever statistics you want, depending on what you want to express.

Some random notes:

- If there is a greater than $.5$ probability that a company will go bankrupt in the $n$th year (for example the second year) you can safely say the company will *most likely* go bankrupt in this year rather than any other year, based on your model.
- If you have only calculated probabilities for one year, two years, and three years, and they come out to $.1, .2, .1$, you cannot necessarily say the company will most likely go bankrupt in the second year.  For, it could turn out that the probability for the fourth year is $.4$, higher than the other three.
- In the above case, if you wanted to add them up $(.1 + .2 + .1 = .4)$ and then say that the company will go bankrupt in the second year with probability $.5$, you must say it this way: "*Given* that the company goes bankrupt in the next three years, the company will go bankrupt in the second year with probability $.5$."

Comment: They are independent models. Each model is trained separately with different data so each probability is independent. If I would only use 1 model I can say that the model calculates the probability of bankruptcy happening during next 1 year period however I have model for 2nd and 3rd year also. I hope I described my problem more clearly and sorry for my English, it is not my native language.

Comment: @user3296317 But does the 2nd year model calculate whether it happens in the second year *given* that it did *not* happen in the first year?  Or the probability it happens in the second year at all, given nothing?

Comment: I think yes. I try to give an example. I have data about company X that bankrupted in year Y. When training model 1 I use the features from year Y, when training model 2 then variables from Y-1 basically I am trying to capture the state of the bankrupted company Y-n years before bankruptcy. When making predictions I use input company today features on each model and the prediction function of each model returns probability between 0-1 for that input. Btw im using random forests if it helps anything.

Comment: Can I say based on the probabilities in my question:
a) The probability of company going bankrupt in 2nd year is 80%
b) The probability of company going bankrupt in 3rd year is 50%
c) Given that the bankruptcy will hapen during next 3 years, the most probable year is 2nd year with the probability of 47%

Comment: @Ilves I'm sorry but I *really* do not understand what it means for your model to predict an $80 \%$ chance of bankruptcy in the second month and at the same time a different model to predict a probability of $50\%$ of bankruptcy in the third month.  Those two models are inconsistent.  They cannot coexist and both be anything close to accurate.  And if not, then I don't know the details of how your model works, but I need to know exactly *what it is* the model is outputting--what that number $.8$ or $.5$ *means*.

Comment: It is binary classification model and outputs 2 probabilities (A - Yes bankruptcy will happen, B - No it would not) A+B = 1. You have to observe the models separately as they are trained independently using different data depending on the month before the bankruptcy the model is trying to classify. The main purpose of my work was to sutudy how well models can classify bankrupcy depending on the period before bankruptcy however I would like to propose practical application to these models but im not sure how to intepret/describe the results. Thank you for u'r patience, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Ilves OK, you say "they are trained independently using different data depending on the month before the bankruptcy the model is trying to classify."  Could you ellaborate on that?  What exactly does the data it is trained on have in common?

Comment: @Ilves You keep saying that "You have to observe the models separately", but this isn't really a way out.  If any of the models were really computing the probability of a given company to go bankrupt in the given year, then the fact that the probabilities they return add up to more than one wouldn't mean they are independent models, it would mean none of the models is accurate.  Therefore, the models must be returning a *conditional* probability, but I need to know what that conditional probability is.

Comment: I try to give example. Training set sample with 1 feature A) Bankrupted, Net worth 1 month before bankruptcy X USD, 2 months before x+RAND() USD etc. Model 1 is train with net worth 1 month before bankruptcy, Model 2 is trained net worh 2 months before bankruptcy. Predicting: Now I use sample B that today has net worth of y USD on both models and I get probability for each model. In reality there are thousends of samples both bankrupted and normal.

Comment: @Ilves OK, I still don't know exactly *what* probability the model predicts, you keep saying it outputs a "probability" but that word is meaningless if you don't specify exactly what probability it is.  I am sorry but I am not terribly interested in this problem at this point and I am going to move on to other things.  Long discussions in the comments are to be avoided.  I appreciate you trying to explain this to me and I'm sorry I couldn't help.  Feel free to ask a new question if you have a different way to phrase your question (link back to this one).